# Aws cli command to get the list of instances detail from aws workspace

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-workspaces

Aws cli command to get the list of instances detail from aws workspace like Workspace ID, IP Address, Subnet ID, Computer Name,Running Mode from aws cli?

Comment: Have you checked the [describe-workspaces](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/workspaces/describe-workspaces.html) command?

Comment: Adding output as table helped. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly from your question, you want aws cli command to get the details of workspaces, then here is the command:

```
aws workspaces describe-workspaces
```

It will give you list of all workspaces with details such as username, workspaceId, IPAddress, Subnet Id etc. Hope this will help.